# Ionic-React interface value is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, interface, null

I'm trying to make an input area, and get the values from it.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Now i'm using interfaces, because of Component ReadOnly error from constructor=> this.state= {value: 'xx'};

```
interface AbcState {
    value: 'Type some lyrics here'
 }

class ChordEditor extends React.Component<{}, AbcState> {
   constructor(props: any){
       super(props);
       this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);

   }

   handleChange(e: any){
    this.setState({
        value: e.target.value
    });
   }


 render (){
   return (
   <div className="chord-editor">
       <div className="panel">
        <h3>Input</h3>
        <textarea style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        defaultValue={this.state.value}></textarea>
       </div>
       <div className="panel">

       </div>
   </div>
   );
 }
}

export default ChordEditor;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not what interfaces are for. You cannot set default values with an interface, they only describe the data **type**.

The null value error is because you have declared a constructor without state. As you can see [here in the react source](https://github.com/gaearon/react/blob/d385fe342809e33b92022c47ee0f7ff09ce7920c/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js#L492), react will default `this.state` to null, if nothing is given.

As you can see in the working snippet below, setting state with an initial value in the constructor does work as expected:

```js
class ChordEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {value: 'Type some lyrics here'}
  }

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render (){
    return (
       <div className="chord-editor">
         <div className="panel">
           <h3>Input</h3>
           <textarea 
             style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
             onChange={this.handleChange}
             defaultValue={this.state.value}
            ></textarea>
         </div>
         <div className="panel">
         </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ChordEditor />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: any
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>', I'm using Ionic with react

Comment: Did you change the interface to be `value: string` instead of the value?